# Deleting Row AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, security

There is a smarter way to delete a row by ajax request?

Here code I use, maybe there is a better and more secure way.

BUTTON

```
<a href="#" msg_id="<? echo $msg_id; ?>" class="delete-btn"> DELETE </a>
```

AJAX

```
$('.delete-btn').click(function(){

            // Confirm
            ///if ( ! confirm('Are you sure want to delete this row?')){
            //    return false;
           // }

            // id need to delete
            var msg_id = $(this).attr('msg_id');

            // Current button 
            var obj = this;

            // Delete by ajax request
            $.ajax({
                type : "post",
                dataType : "text",
                url : 'messages_sql.inc.php?a=message_delete',
                data : {
                    msg_id : msg_id
                },
                success : function(result){
                    $(obj).parent().parent().remove();
                    window.location.assign('messages.php?msg=deleted');
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: What does `messages_sql.inc.php` do? Does it check the user's session to confirm they have privileges to delete the record they will delete?

Comment: You shouldn't make up your own attributes. Use `data-msg_id` instead of `msg_id`.

Comment: messages_sql.inc.php have SQL QUERY only $msg_id = $_POST['msg_id'];

   $sql = "DELETE FROM db_messages WHERE msg_id = $msg_id";

Comment: As long as the server performs proper validation, this is the normal way to do it.

Comment: You should use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Do not do SQL queries like that. Parameterize the query. `WHERE msg_id =  ?` then bind `$msg_id`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review (and this thus too broad / opinion based). It could probably be adjusted to be on topic for [the code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Based on this comment

> messages_sql.inc.php have SQL QUERY only $msg_id = $_POST['msg_id']; $sql = "DELETE FROM db_messages WHERE msg_id = $msg_id";

there are a few security concerns:

Without validating the AJAX request is from someone you trust, anyone on the internet can delete records from your table.  If your application requires a user to login, keep track of their session and check it when processing the AJAX request.  Otherwise pass a CSRF token with the AJAX request to at least confirm it's from someone actually browsing your page.

Next, you may need to [confirm the user making the request is allowed to delete the row](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2017-A4-Broken_Access_Control) from `db_messages`.  For example, is a user only allowed to delete their own rows from this table?  If so, you will need to check their user ID against the active session.

Also use prepared statements with parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection attacks.